# Tanstack Table React how to recalculate width of all columns when resize

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I expand one column, I want to shrink the size of others.
There is an example https://tanstack.com/table/latest/docs/framework/react/examples/column-resizing-performant
which I change to something like this

```
  const columnSizeRef = useRef<Record<string, number>>({});
  const columnSizeVars = useMemo(() => {
    let colSizes: { [key: string]: number } = {};

    if (columnSizingInfo.isResizingColumn) {
      const deltaOffset = columnSizingInfo.deltaOffset!;
      const columnsNotResizedCount = allHeaders.length - 1;
      const deltaOffsetForColumnNotResized = (-1 * deltaOffset) / columnsNotResizedCount;

      console.log(deltaOffset, deltaOffsetForColumnNotResized);
      for (let i = 0; i < allHeaders.length; i++) {
        const header = allHeaders[i]!;

        if (columnSizingInfo.isResizingColumn === header.id) {
          colSizes[header.id] = columnSizeRef.current[header.id]! + deltaOffset;
        } else {
          colSizes[header.id] = columnSizeRef.current[header.id]! + deltaOffsetForColumnNotResized;
        }
      }
      columnSizeRef.current = colSizes;
    } else {
      if (_.isEmpty(columnSizeRef.current)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < allHeaders.length; i++) {
          const header = allHeaders[i]!;
          colSizes[header.id] = header.getSize();
        }
        columnSizeRef.current = colSizes;
      } else {
        colSizes = columnSizeRef.current;
      }
    }

    return colSizes;
  }, [columnSizingInfo, allHeaders]);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to get this type of behaviour?